# Problems with GNUplot in rotating labels in a given plane in a 3D plot

Tags: 3d, rotation, label, gnuplot

I hope everyone is fine in this quarantine.

I have a 3D plot and I need to put some text (labels) in a given position and then to rotate the text in the x-y plane.

However, when I try

```
set label 4 'Corporative' at 3.6, 0.6, 0.0 font ",18" rotate by -90.0 tc lt 2
```

the text `"Corporative"` is rotated perpendicularly to the x-y plane. See the figure below.

[image: Off-plane text label after rotation]

Is there a way to impose the rotation in the x-y plane?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the axis labels, yes.  For example you could say

```
  set ylabel "Escopo" rotate parallel
```

For "set label", no.